# Relay Emails with Java

Tags: java, email

I want my software (java-based) to relay messages send to a certain address to a given group of recipients.

For example:

> Messages to `group1@mysite.com` are relayed to everyone who is part of group1.

Therefor I catch all mails send to `group1@mysite.com`, and want to send them to each person individually, but this person should not see the other recipients, but he should still see who this message was originally intended for.

For example:

> Part of Group1 are: `James@yahoo.com`, `stacy@gmx.net` and `francis@gmail.com`. They all get the original message with `group1@mysite.com` as "**TO**"-Recipient and not seeing who is in this group.

I thought about putting them all in **BCC**, but then I will not have the **TO**-Recipient set. And if I set the **TO**-Recipient I will get the message again and relay it again, which produces and endless loop.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well, if you are both the recipient of the mails that you want to relay to a group AND are in a group itself, you have a recursion in your data structure and should rightfully get a recursion in your mail delivery. I suggest removing yourself as either recipient or from the group altogether.

Comment: I think you misunderstood, what I want: I want to create a service in my software, which catches messages send to a certain address (which is mine) and relay it to the members of the group, that are part of this certain address, much like a mailing list.

Comment: Then you need to explain this some more. You are listening on group1@mysite.com, relaying to James@yahoo.com, stacy@gmx.net and francis@gmail.com. How is relaying a mail to these 3 people causing YOU to get the message again ("I will get the message again")?

Comment: I do not want the recipients (james, stacy, francis) to see themselves as the recipient, but to keep seeing group1@mysite.com as recipient, although they will get it. If I catch the message and resend it, by adding them as BCC recipient, I will catch the message again on the next event, since I did not remove group1@mysite.com as TO recipient, because I want them to see group1@mysite.com as recipient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to act like an mailinglist, you need to work like a mailing list.
They acutaly send out a e-mail for every member.

So you need to send 3 mails to james@yahoo.com stacy@gmx.net and francis@gmail.com

If you want to set the To: field to group1@mysite.com you have to track the message id's of your own sent e-mails, to prevent loops

Comment: There is no other way, than to save the messageID and exclude it from being relayed again? I was looking for a solution other than that, because that is not the way I wanted it to fix.

Comment: you also can set a X-DoNotRelayAgain, or what ever you want, field to your mail header. And if this field is in a incoming mail, don't relay it